# Can you attack with spells while concentrating on another?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat

On page 203 of the *Player's Handbook* it says that you can attack while concentrating on a spell. Does that include *spell* attacks like Magic Missile, or is it just physical melee attacks?

Comment: Minor quibble: [Dealing damage doesn't make something an attack. An attack roll—or being called an attack—makes it an attack.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/643952581983645696). So Magic Missile is not an attack for rules purposes.

Comment: [Related] [Is a spell with an attack roll "an attack" for the purpose of Sneak Attack?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33923) • [What counts as an attack?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71245)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can make spell attacks whilst concentrating, so long as those spells don't also require concentration. Casting Magic Missile whilst you're concentrating is fine.

From the [Basic Rules PDF](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/PlayerDnDBasicRules_v0.2_PrintFriendly.pdf), page 80 (the section on Concentration begins at the very end of page 79):

> Normal activity, such as moving and attacking, doesn’t interfere with concentration. The following factors can break concentration:
>
> - **Casting another spell that requires concentration.** You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can’t concentrate on two spells at once.

The other triggers mentioned are taking damage (which has only a chance of breaking concentration), being incapacitated or killed, or GM fiat based on changes in the environment around you. Casting another non-concentration spell seems OK.

Though some GMs could use that GM fiat clause to suggest something happens to your concentration.

Comment: Thanks. I was incorrect in thinking that an attack meant it had to be physical in nature for some strange reason.